# Can I have multiple levels of nested cloned forms using SheepIt JQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-plugins

I have tried, with no avail, to create a nestedForm inside of another nestedForm using the SheepIt! plugin. Is this even possible?

Extending [Demo 7](http://www.mdelrosso.com/sheepit/index.php?lng=en_GB&sec=demo7) on the SheepIt! website, I tried to add an additional nested form in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YWZ8K/1/)

But I get a indexOf error...

Remove the following section to get rid of the error but break the intended functionality: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YWZ8K/)

```
,
         nestedForms: [
        {
                id: 'person_addresses_#index#_phones_#index_phones#_tests',
                    options: {
                indexFormat: '#index_tests#'
            }
        }
         ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [JSFiddle Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/njB5t/)

It seems that the SheepIt! plugin only likes to see one index in nestedForm ID. It was giving me the indexOf error because it was hitting the first #index#. You can still use multiple indexes in your inputs and it will fill them out as expected.

Comment: So it appears that this is not a complete solution. Creating 'tests' only works for the first address.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to function normalizeFieldsForForm after "that" declaration

```
var nameTemplateAttr = that[0]['name'];
```