# SheepIt multiple levels of nested

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have problem with SheepIt plugin. I trying to do multi nested forms, but 3rd level form not working. I looked on this question [Can I have multiple levels of nested cloned forms using SheepIt JQuery plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047937/can-i-have-multiple-levels-of-nested-cloned-forms-using-sheepit-jquery-plugin).

This is my work: http://jsfiddle.net/aEfFE/2/

As you can see there is no problem when you click on "Dodaj plik" or "Dodaj wersje", but when you click on "Dodaj odcinek", the whole form are crashed. Field file is added only to first element of form.

My html:

```
<div class="anime-form-container">
            <div id="addEpisodeForm">
                <!-- Form template-->
                <div id="addEpisodeForm_template">
                    <label for="addEpisodeForm_#index#_episodeNumber">Numer odcinka <span id="addEpisodeForm_label"></span></label>
                    <input id="addEpisodeForm_#index#_episodeNumber" name="anime[episode][#index#][episodeNumber]" type="text" size="15" maxlength="10" />
                    <a id="addEpisodeForm_remove_current"><img class="delete" src="<?=ADRES_THEME?>images/cross.png" width="16" height="16" border="0"></a>


                    <!-- Embeded sheepIt Form -->
                    <div style="margin-left:50px; overflow:hidden;">
                        <label>Wersje</label>

                        <div id="addEpisodeForm_#index#_episodeVersion">

                            <!-- Nested form template-->
                            <div id="addEpisodeForm_#index#_episodeVersion_template">
                                <label for="addEpisodeForm_#index#_episodeVersion_#index_episodeVersion#_version">Wersja <span id="addEpisodeForm_#index#_episodeVersion_label"></span></label>
                                <select id="addEpisodeForm_#index#_episodeVersion_#index_episodeVersion#_version" name="anime[episode][#index#][episodeNumber][#index_episodeVersion#][version]" >
                                    <option>1</option>
                                    <option>2</option>
                                </select>
                                <a id="addEpisodeForm_#index#_episodeVersion_remove_current"><img src="<?=ADRES_THEME?>images/cross.png" width="16" height="16" border="0"></a>


                                <!-- Embeded Embedded sheepIt Form --> 
                                <div style="margin-left:50px; overflow:hidden;">
                                <label>Pliki</label>      
                                    <div id="episodeVersion_#index_episodeVersion#_episodeFile">

                                        <!-- Nested form template-->
                                        <div id="episodeVersion_#index_episodeVersion#_episodeFile_template">
                                            <label for="episodeVersion_#index_episodeVersion#_episodeFile_#index_EpisodeFile#_file">Plik <span id="episodeVersion_#index_episodeVersion#_episodeFile_label"></span></label>
                                            <input id="episodeVersion_#index_episodeVersion#_episodeFile_#index_EpisodeFile#_file" name="anime[episode][#index#][episodeNumber][#index_episodeVersion#][version][#index_EpisodeFile][file]" type="text" size="15" maxlength="10" />
                                            <a id="episodeVersion_#index_episodeVersion#_episodeFile_remove_current"><img src="<?=ADRES_THEME?>images/cross.png" width="16" height="16" border="0"></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- /Nested form template-->

                                        <!-- No forms template -->
                                        <div id="episodeVersion_#index_episodeVersion#_episodeFile_noforms_template">Brak plików</div>
                                        <!-- /No forms template-->

                                        <!-- Controls -->
                                        <div id="episodeVersion_#index_episodeVersion#_episodeFile_controls" class="controls">
                                            <div id="episodeVersion_#index_episodeVersion#_episodeFile_add"><a><span>Dodaj plik</span></a></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- /Controls -->

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /Embeded Embedded sheepIt Form -->



                            </div>
                            <!-- /Nested form template-->

                            <!-- No forms template -->
                            <div id="addEpisodeForm_#index#_episodeVersion_noforms_template">Brak wersji</div>
                            <!-- /No forms template-->

                            <!-- Controls -->
                            <div id="addEpisodeForm_#index#_episodeVersion_controls" class="controls">
                                <div id="addEpisodeForm_#index#_episodeVersion_add"><a><span>Dodaj wersje</span></a></div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /Controls -->

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <!-- /Embeded sheepIt Form -->


                </div>
                <!-- /Form template-->

                <!-- No forms template -->
                    <div id="addEpisodeForm_noforms_template">Brak odcinków</div>
                <!-- /No forms template-->

                <!-- Controls -->
                <div id="addEpisodeForm_controls">
                    <div id="addEpisodeForm_add"><a><span>Dodaj odcinek</span></a></div>
                </div>
                <!-- /Controls -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

And js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var sheepItForm = $('#addEpisodeForm').sheepIt({
                separator: '',
                allowRemoveLast: false,
                allowRemoveCurrent: true,
                allowRemoveAll: false,
                allowAdd: true,
                allowAddN: true,
                maxFormsCount: 0,
                minFormsCount: 1,
                iniFormsCount: 1,
                nestedForms: [{
                        id: 'addEpisodeForm_#index#_episodeVersion',
                        options: { 
                             indexFormat: '#index_episodeVersion#',
                             maxFormsCount: 0,
                             nestedForms: [{
                                id: 'episodeVersion_#index_episodeVersion#_episodeFile',
                                options: {
                                    indexFormat: '#index_EpisodeFile#',
                                    minFormsCount: 1,
                                    iniFormsCount: 1

                                }}
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });

        });
```

Comment: Your code helped me get the two level nested code working. Thanks.